# Integral version of Ampere's law: why current outside the surface does not contribute to $\oint B\cdot d\ell$?

Tags: electromagnetism

I have a question about why this is true

$\oint B\cdot d\ell = \mu_0$ $I_{enclosed}$

My problem is that I am not really seeing visually or mathematically why the magnetic field generated by a current that doesn’t pass through the loop will not contribute to the integral.

Any advice or intuition is aprecciated thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that the magnetic field lines are circular around the wire. If the wire is inside the loop all contribution to the line integral will have the same sign, but if the wire is outside the loop there will be both, positive and negative contributions, and these cancel each other. One easy example is if the wire is infinitely far away and creates a constant magnetic field parallel to the plane of the loop. Here it is easy to see, by looking at the angles between the field and the loop, that the integral on one half of the loop cancels the integral on the other half of the loop.

Comment: What I don't quite understand is, that why, in the straight wire example, is $\oint \vec{B}\cdot \mathrm d l=0$? That is, how do I prove that?  The angles between the entering $\vec{B}$ and $\mathrm dl$ and outgoing $\vec{B} $ and $\mathrm d l$ aren't equal. although $|\vec{B}|$ is definitely equal as it lies on the circular path. Of course, in the extreme case, when wire is at infinity I understand as B is parallel/anti parallel to dl.